# Trying to fire/call OnLoggedIn event from Page_Load event

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, login-control

I am implementing ASP.NET User Membership authentication in a website.
I am using ASP.NET's control to

- authenticate user,
- sign up new user and
- change password to change the authenticated user's password.

My functionality is:

- On Sign Up page, I have User name and Email as inputs and I have set the`AutoGeneratePassword` property to `true`.
- Once successful registration system sends out an email to that user with a URL in email (like `http://localhost:xxxx/Login.aspx?user=abc10&pwd=something`).

My issue is, when user clicks above link, he should be redirected automatically to change password page to change the password.
So, for redirection, I am trying to call the `OnLoggedIn` event in `page_Load`.

I have tried below calls from `page_Load` event.

1. `Login1_LoggedIn(sender.GetType(), null)`
2. `login.LoggedIn += new EventHandler(Login1_LoggedIn)`

But the event is not firing, can anybody help?

Comment: I don't think you can call the OnLoggedIn event.  The user has not logged in yet.  Try working with page_Loading event.

Comment: There is no page_Loading event I found. But there is an improvement I am sharing. From my above tries, event is now firing and it is taking to the change password page too. But next issue is, on change password page, the logged in user is not authenticated. It means, the Request.IsAuthenticated property returns false. And hence, it is again asking me to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured that out. As I had to work out two scenarios, 
I. The user should be able to login from the login page.
II. And when user should be able to redirect to next page following login when he/she clicks the link they have received in their email.

So the first point is very straight forward.

For the second point, I created a method which has all code logic to authenticate the user. And called this method in page_load() event and from OnLoggedIn event.

And in page load, I wrote below code to simulate login event to redirect user directly to next page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
string username = usernameTextbox.Text.Trim();
**FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);**
callLogin();// this method where in my user authentication logic resides
}
```